# Swipe Gesture not working in xcode

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Since Xcode got updated, i can't use swipe gesture. I have 2 UIViewController, i dragged a Swipe Gesture in the first and in the second. I connected them with Modal Action Segue. I tried in the simulator and on my device and both didn't work. It's so simple and i used to be able to do it but now it just doesn't work. Am i missing something ? I tried playing with the "State: Enable button" but that didn't worked. Normally i would just do a navigation bar with a button to change view but for this app i really want to you swipe gesture... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That was a stupid mistake... I dragged the Swipe Gestures on the background images. You need do drag them on the view itself. Just move the background image and drag the swipe gesture on the UIView and it should work!

Answer (score -1):

Lol, I'm having trouble with that too.

I fixed it by making swipe gesture programatically